# WSO2IS multiple users store

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Is possible to set a Service Provider to use a specific user store?

Ex.: I have a secondary user store, foo.com that uses JDBC, and other secondary user store, foo.net that uses LDAP.

I have two service providers, I want tha first SP called mobile uses the foo.com user store only to authenticate via oauth2, and the other SP foo.net uses the foo.net user store.

Thats is possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is really what I want to know. Multiple tenant is a solution. Make this two service providers belong to different tenants.Then service providers can use different user store.
However, I think there should be other solutions.

Comment: The problem to use multiple tenants, is this, user have to use the domain of the tenant, now, how to do this when user login is your email? Like this, user@foo.com@foo.com, how I can explain to user, that him has to use your login like this?

Answer (score 0):

For authenticate functionality you don't have to bind Service Provider with specific User store. In mobile application scenario it will recursively go through all user stores and user will be authenticated against foo.com user store. In order to provide comprehensive answer can please provide what are the protocols you are using in both service providers like in first SP oauth, saml and second SP saml, scim.

Comment: Both SP's use oauth2 protocol, my question is only to know how to restrict authentication per user store in the SP.

Comment: If you can provide domain qualified username like <user store domain> / <username> authentication will be restricted to given user store domain